# Subsetting a pandas dataframe based on the match between df's column names and a list of column names with repeated names

Tags: python, pandas

I have list of column names with duplicated names, for example:
`list = ['col1', 'col3', 'col1']`

and a pandas dataframe that some of its column names match the list items:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
 a       c        e       g
 b       d        f       h
```

I would like to subset the dataframe so that the returned df would have col1, col2 and again col1 like:

```
 col1   col2     col1
   a    c        a
   b    d        b
```

I have tried

```
names = ['col1', 'col4', 'col1']
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a','b'],'col2': ['c', 'd'], 'col3': ['e', 'f'], 'col4': ['g', 'h']} )
df2 = df[df.columns & names]
df2
```

which returns only col1 and col4 without duplicating col1:

```
col1    col4
  a      g
  b      h
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass a list to the DataFrame indexing operator, containing all the columns you want to extract (including repeats).

```py
# The names of the columns to be extracted, including duplicates. 
names = ['col1', 'col2', 'col1']

# Create a new DataFrame made up only of the columns from the list.
df2 = df[names]

print(df2)
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2 col1
0    a    c    a
1    b    d    b
```